# the wordpress show The optional module, zip, is not installed, or has been disabled

Tags: php, wordpress

the wordpress show I do not have zip module
I use this command

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/zip-1.18.2.tgz
tar -zxvf zip-1.18.2.tgz
cd zip-1.18.2
/usr/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
make
make install
make test
```

and then I write this in /etc/php.ini

```
extension=zip.so
```

then I use `php -m` to check,but still no zip module

I ue another way,I search this

```
yum search php74|grep zip
```

it show there is a zip .
then I use this command :

```
yum -y install php73-php-pecl-zip.x86_64
```

then I use `php -m` to check,still mo zip module

what should I do now?